# How to create unique index that allows duplicates for null and other specified values

Tags: mongodb, indexing

I have a "header.header.message-id" in my document JSON structure for which I created an index, that looks like this in an output from db.archives.getIndexes():

```
{
"key": {
  "header.header.message-id": 1
},
"name": "header.header.message-id_index",
"v": 2,
"background": false
}
```

I need to create an index that allows duplicates for null and other specified values. For example, I want to accept when "header.header.message-id" is empty, as well as if it equals: "#1/1" (which appears a lot in my documents). Other than that, all duplicates should be rejected.

Comment: [check partial and sparse indexes](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-partial/)?

Comment: I tried `db.meow.createIndex({"item":1},{"unique":true, partialFilterExpression:{item:{$ne:null, $ne:"#1/1"}}})` but this ain't possible, `$ne` isn't allowed

Comment: There must be some way. I wonder if $gt would work

Comment: Hopefully someone else will help, I don't see a way tbh

Comment: Minsky, I have figured out the answer, see below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, did not get an answer on this site, but I have eventually figured it out.
The index had to be defined in the following way to ensure it's only accepting unique values for key "header.header.message-id", except for null values and those that equal to "#1/1".

```
  {
    "key": {
      "header.header.message-id": 1
    },
    "name": "header.header.message-id_index",
    "partialFilterExpression": {
      "header.header.message-id": {
        "$exists": true,
        "$gt": "#1/1"
      }
    },
    "unique": true
  }
```

I've tested it and it works as specified.

Comment: it's good to know, but the only reason I didnt suggest that was `$gt:"#1/1"` makes no sense unless you actually include what other data is in there. Anyways...

Comment: It actually does make sense, this specification says: 1. Accept Unique values; 2. Except for Null values (empty or missing key header.header.message-id); 3. And also except for values that equal to: "#1/1". Tested, works exactly as I needed it to work.

Comment: Why $gt instead of $ne?

Comment: I wanted to use $ne (that matches all values that are not equal to a specified value) but that caused the error (unsupported expression in partial index), so the next one to try was $gt which matches values that are greater than a specified value. It was not exactly an obvious choice based on the specification, but it works. Also note, I did not try any of the operators that matches arrays, that could be something to test.

Comment: Thanks for the solution which works great, but what does #1/1 (I imagine length of first field) but where is this documented?